# How to call a variabe of an inner class correctly

Tags: python, variables, inner-classes

I would like to set the value of an inner class and call it from out of any class. I use the same thing for the (outer)class, the value gets changed in the set def, but outside of that function it ooks like is hasnt changed.

my code looks like this

```
class car(vehicle):
    __vehicle_kind = "car"
    __nb_of_wheels = 4
    __nb_of_doors = 2

    def showKind(self):
        return self.__vehicle_kind

    def showNbOfWheels(self):
        return self.__nb_of_wheels

    def showNbOfDoors(self):
        return self.__nb_of_doors

    class wheels(vehicle):
        wheel_color = "grey"
        wheel_diametre = "16"

        def setWheelColor(self, color):
            self.wheel_color = color
            print self.wheel_color

        def showWheelColor(self):
            return self.wheel_color
```

I set and call the showWheelColor with:

```
new.wheels().setWheelColor(wheel_color)
print new.wheels().showWheelColor()
```

but the show returns the old value.
How to make this work correctly?

Comment: Start by not thinking of "private" as anything in Python.

Comment: Both `wheels` and `car` are derivatives of `vehicle` which doesn't make sense to me. Could you either give code for `vehicle` class or explain your logic behind it (How are wheels a vehicle?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your example has a few issues. The main issue is that you're confusing class and instance variables/members. The `wheel_color = "grey"` is a class variable that applies to all instances of `wheel`, while the `self.wheel_color = color` refers to an instance variable that only applies to that particular instance.

This in addition to the fact that `new.wheels()` will provide a new instance every time it's called you would first take a new instance of `wheels` and set it's `wheel_color` and then create another instance and check it's `wheel_colors`, but since you haven't set the instance variable on that python would resort to checking the class variable - which is still `"grey"`